# Raspberry Pi RTC on i2c-0

Tags: raspberry-pi, i2c, adafruit, real-time-clock

I am looking to add a real-time clock to my Raspberry Pi using i2c, but I want to use **i2c-0** (GPIO 0 and GPIO 1) rather than **i2c-1** (GPIO 2 and GPIO 3). The real-time clock gets detected by the Raspberry Pi, but when I add

> dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,ds1307

to **/boot/config.txt**, it doesn’t say ‘UU’ (in use) instead of the address (68) when using

> i2cdetect -y 0

Is there any way of adding something to the config.txt file in order to target the i2c-0 instead of the i2c-1?

I used the [Adafruit tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/adding-a-real-time-clock-to-raspberry-pi/set-rtc-time) in order to add it, but obviously only worked when connecting to the i2c-1 and not i2c-0.

Comment: Of course, you could write your own program that talks to the RTC, but I suppose that's not what you want.